# internal ajax call from object is clearing member variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop

I have the object

```
var MyObject = (function (){

     var MyObject = function (a,b){
          this.A = a;
          this.B = b;
          this.C;


     }

     MyObject.prototype.PublicFunction = function(){

          var someVariable = 123; //this.A and this.B are both fine here.
          var self = this;
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/PageMethod",
            data: "{" + args + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, status) {  
             //this.A = undefined, this.B = undefined, this.C = the data.
             self.C = data.d
             },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){

             alert('tears');



          }
       });
     }


return MyObject;
}());
```

As I enter the prototype function `this.A\B` are both the values from the constructor. After the ajax call is executed `this.A\B` are both `undefined`. I'm not sure what to do here. I probably don't understand scope in objects like I need to. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you include more of the ajax hooplah?

Comment: You can bind the success function to `this`. `function(data){...}.bind(this)`

Comment: Due to a discussion in the chat system: **This needs to be supported on IE6+**, so .bind will not work, also the entire .prototype thing might not work. I'm forgetful if IE6/7 support extending .prototype

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your question earlier, your Success function is most likely getting executed without a context (and therefore it is in the global context where `this == window`)

Just try logging `this` (`console.log(this)`) inside your success function - you'll see that it's the `window` object.

A common workaround to the problem you're having is to create a local reference to `this` like the following:

```
 MyObject.prototype.PublicFunction = function(){
     var self = this;
      var someVariable = 123; //this.A and this.B are both fine here.
      //AJAX HOOPLAH
      Success(data) {
          self.C = data.d

          //this.A = undefined, this.B = undefined, this.C = the data.
      }
      Fail{
        alert('tears');
      }

 }
```